# How do i convert this Js function to Anonymous function in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

this function is called on Load  how do i convert this to jquery Anonymous function . I tried but it is giving me Object Expected Error . Moreover I have made  call to  the below 
setTab() in 20 files so i cannot Change the Signature of the calling it should be same as (setTab("Test")) but the Implementation needs to be changed to Anonymous function which accepts a  parameter.

//old JS func()

```
   function setTab(selection) {
         $("#"+selection).css('background', '#CC0000');
         $("#"+selection).css('color', '#ffffff');       
    }
```

//jquery Anonynous Func

```
    var setsTab = (function (selection) {
     $("#"+selection).css('background', '#CC0000');
     $("#"+selection).css('color', '#ffffff');  
})();
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?  It's a bit unclear.  Could you point us to an example where this is done?

Comment: Where is the rest of the HTML?  Are you including jQuery itself?  Are you enclosing your code in jQuery's `document.ready`?

Comment: @JaredPar: Iam Trying to Change the Definition of the existing JS function to anonymous Function or Closure (it Should Accept The Same Parameter Selection).And Moreover i Should call the Function with the same Signature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have setup a self executing anonymous function, meaning setsTab is set to what the function returns (undefined) because the function is called as soon as it is made (that's what the paren group at the end of the statement does, calls the function);

What i would do is

```
var setsTab = function(selection) {
     $("#"+selection).css('background', '#CC0000');
     $("#"+selection).css('color', '#ffffff');  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want it this way?

```
var setsTab = function (selection) {
     $("#"+selection).css('background', '#CC0000');
     $("#"+selection).css('color', '#ffffff');  
}
```

Edit: But this doesn't have anything to do with jQuery. (`anonymous jquery function`?)

Comment: Or "anonymous functions" once a name is given :p The key difference from the post is the function-object is *not invoked* first, but rather assigned to the variable.